# Create a list of documents based on an original list of documents mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called `user` which consists of user information.

Within that user collection I have an array of `skills` specific to the user.

How would I create an collection from every `skill` that every user has so that I can use that list as a lookup table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have data structured like this:

```js
db.users.insert({name:'ninja', skills: ['katana', 'shuriken']});
db.users.insert({name:'developer', skills: ['c#', 'sql', 'katana', 'mongodb']});
```

you could use an [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) to get a list of the all the `skills` in your `users` have.

More specifically, the aggregation could look like this:

```js
db.users.aggregate([ 
    { $unwind: '$skills' },
    { $group: {_id: '$skills'} }
]);
```

There are two steps in the aggregation above:

- the [unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) creates a list of all (non-unique) skills and the users they belong to
- the [group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) will produce a unique list of all skills

*Note: To get a better understanding of what the `$unwind` step does, you can run the aggregation with only that step: `db.users.aggregate([ { $unwind: '$skills' } ]);`*

The results of the two-step aggregation above look like this:

```js
{
    "result": [
        {   "_id": "mongodb"   }, 
        {   "_id": "sql"       },
        {   "_id": "c#"        }, 
        {   "_id": "shuriken"  }, 
        {   "_id": "katana"    }
    ],
    "ok": 1
}
```

Finally, in order to save these results to a new collection called `skills`, you can run the following commands in the mongo shell:

```js
> var unique_skills = db.users.aggregate([ { $unwind: '$skills' }, { $group: {_id: '$skills'} } ]).result;
> db.skills.insert(unique_skills);
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay in accepting the answer! How would I use your example to rebuild on demand?

Comment: That depends on your scenario. If there's not much data, you could run the aggregation each time you need it and use its result directly (not persisting it to any collection). Otherwise, you could write a procedure that refreshes the data. If you have huge amounts of data, you may want to look into [incremental map-reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-incremental-map-reduce/)

Comment: +1 After building an aggregation, do you access it as a collection? How would I search / query it?

Comment: The results of the aggregation are volatile. I see it more like a view in the RDBMs world. In the example above, in order to avoid calculating things over and over again, I chose to persist the aggregation results to a collection that can be queries as many times as you'd like. You can decide whether that's good in your scenario. You may for example prefer to run the aggregation each time, if you don't have great amounts of data.

Comment: Is that where system functions kick in? I'm brand new to Mongo (as I've sure you have already guessed :))

Comment: @user2877629 I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: With using the aggregation framework, do you run this query everytime or is it like an index? If its like an index, do you build a system task / stored procedure to keep it re-aggregating?

Comment: @user2877629 Aggregation is like a query you run every time. For index-like behavior you may want to read about [incremental map-reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-incremental-map-reduce/)